# How to introduce TS into a plain JS project, and publish it as JS+JSDoc library for TypeScript consumers?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

### Problem:

I haven't been able to find a nice way to do this. Here's what I tried:

- First, ensure that `allowJs` and `checkJs` are both `true` in `tsconfig.json`, then include the files of your project, for the most part.

When writing files inside the project (which we wish to publish as a library on NPM), type checking works great: one JS file (with JSDoc comments for type annotations) can be imported into any other JS file. All is great.

Now, the trouble comes with publishing this project, and getting the types to be visible in a downstream dependency. For example, making the types be visible in an app that installs the published project as a package with `npm install the-package`.

Ok, with the project working well locally, now we try to publish. Here are some methods I've tried, taking into account that all my source code is in the project's `src/` folder, and they all have a problem that prevents it from working as needed (each method has an explanation as to why it is not acceptable):

1. Don't output anything:

   - set `types` to `src/index.js`

     - TypeScript will simply not read types from JSDoc comments in JS files, so this simply does not work.
2. Output declarations only:

   - output declarations in separate folder

     - set `emitDeclarationOnly` to `true`
     - set the `outDir` to (for example) `types`.
     - This will output only declaration files to `types`
     - Set `types` in `package.json` to `types/index.d.ts` (for example when `src/index.js` is the package entry point that exports everything from the package)
     - This method work fine when importing from `the-package`, for example `import {whatever} from 'the-package'
     - Unlike with regular TypeScript libraries (which emits JS and declarations together) this method **is broken** when trying to import sub-paths. For example, `import {something} from 'the-package/src/something.js'`. TypeScript will not be able to fine the types for this file (however VS Code will happoly run `Go To Definition` and take you to `something`, and the JSDoc-commented types will be there, but apparently TypeScript likes to ignore them)
   - output declarations as sibling files to the source files

     - set `emitDeclarationOnly` to `true`
     - set the `outDir` to `src` to make the declarations appear in next to all the `.js` files
     - This works at first, any consumer will be able to successfully import anything with full type definitions.
     - Run TypeScript build again, and it will have errors saying `error TS5055: Cannot write file '/the-package/src/something.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file. Basically, TypeScript now considers the declarations that were previously written to now be input files.
3. Output both declaration files and .js files

   - output the files to `types/`

     - while this works, now there are both JS files in `types/`, and JS files in `src/`, duplicating the source for no reason.
     - The location of source must be the same before and after introducing TypeScript, we do not want to change source location for developers, or source location for consumers. *The desired purpose of writing JS + JSDoc is to have a single source of JS files that simply works (regardless if there are type definitions for TS users or not).*
4. Constantly delete sibling .d.ts files before every build

   - output .d.ts files sibling to src/*.js files, and before each build, run `rm -rf src/**/*.d.ts*` first.

     - Without removing the files, but subsequent builds after the output .d.ts files have been created will cause TypeScript to output an errors like these: `error TS5055: Cannot write file '/the-package/path/to/foo.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.`
     - This method will also break many things (for example TypeScript server, or other build tools depending on TS types like ESLint with TS plugins in watch mode) will inevitably break due to source files completely disappearing and reappearing. It will be a bad developer experience with any tooling in place other than the build itself.
5. Try mapping using wildcards in `exports` field in `package.json`

   - I tried this:  `"exports": { "./src/*": { "types": "./types/*", "default": "./src/*" } },`
   - I also tried:  `"exports": { "./src/*.js": { "types": "./types/*.d.ts", "default": "./src/*.js" } },`
   - No luck. Consumer importing a subpath like `import {...} from 'the-package/src/path/foo.js'` does not see types for that file.
6. Output sibling `.d.ts` files in `src/`, and try to make TS exclude those as input files in `tsconfig.json`

   - put this in package.json:   `"include": ["src"], "exclude": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]`
   - This does not work, on any build after `.d.ts` files are generated, TypeScript continues to give errors like in method 4, `error TS5055: Cannot write file ... because it would overwrite input file`.

All of these options are a no-go for various reasions described above.

### More Info:

Here's the tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./types", // for method 2, change this to "./src"

    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "strict": false,

    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,

    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "pota",

    "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.d.ts"] // try to ignore src/*.d.ts files for method 6
}
```

Here's the relevant package.json parts *before* trying to add TypeScript (with parts that I have tried in above methods commented out):

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "//types": "./types/exports.d.ts",
  "//types": "./src/exports.d.ts",
  "main": "./src/exports.js",
  "//exports": {
    "./src/*": {
      "types": "./types/*",
      "default": "./src/*"
    }
  },
}
```

All source files are in `src/**/*.js`. If any declaration files need to be created, they go in `types/` (I wish to not have to generate new files, and for TS to simply pick types up from JSDoc comments when a consumer imports the lib).

To build, the command is simply `tsc` (or `npx tsc` if typescript is not globally installed).

### Question:

How can it be achieved without files from `src/` being duplicated unecessarily to another folder, without causing TS build errors (the sibling .d.ts files in src/), without breaking other tools by deleting sibling .d.ts files on every rebuild, and preferably not emitting any declaration files if possible (but emitting declaration files is ok if necessary)?

**Requirement:** To migrate the JS project (a package) to TypeScript (using JS+JSDoc) developers of the package must continue editing JS files in `src/` and consumers must be able to continue using files in `src/` (method 3 is a no-go).

Comment: Don't you just need `"exclude": ["*.d.ts"]` for the sibling declarations (2b), so they _aren't_ considered input files? Or emit both `.js` and `.d.ts` (3) but only include `dist/` in the package [files](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#files), not `src/` as well.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried that, but it doesn't work, TS still shows the same error for sibling declarations. I updated the question to show more details and to ask a more specific question. I also updated (3) to describe that changing developer's source location, *or* consumer source location, is not acceptable for the solution to introduce TypeScript (devs should continue editing src/, consumers should continue using src/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (thanks @-n- for pointing `typesVersions`!). Use `typesVersions` in `package.json`, like so:

```json
{
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "src/*": ["types/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

Now, simply output declaration files in the `types/` folder, and leave source code in `src/`.

It works as expected! This is excellent for plain JS projects looking to add TypeScript support using JSDoc comments without any of the caveats of the methods described in the OP.

UPDATE the next day after more trial and error:

Using the `exports` field with wildcards in `package.json`, as attempted in the OP's method 5, will work if the `moduleResolution` option is set to `NodeNext` in `tsconfig.json`!

This means that using `exports` that way is good for new projects (but note that it will have additional semantics around exposing or blocking certain files from being importable), and the `typesVersions` trick will work for older projects (it will not expose or block specific files, and all files will be importable).